# App freezes on autocomplete textChanged

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I was able to get the first and last text of user input for AutoCompleteTextview but 
My App freezes when i set the builder method on AutocompleteTextView textChanged method.
I appreciate any effort provided.

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(s.length()>0) {
                String selectedText = s.toString();
                int end = selectedText.length()+start;
                SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(selectedText);
                builder.setSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                Log.i("builderText", " "+builder);
                autoCompleteTextView.setText(builder);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Post your stack-trace.

Comment: It means that neither `start` nor `end` ae matched in your string. Which doesn't surprise me, since you are trying to match two **integers** in a string. Moreover, the string is possibly empty.

Comment: @Rotwang can you give me an idea of how to go about it?

Comment: For instace, by searchin a **string** inside of your string. `int start = startText.indexOf("some string");`. But make sure your string is not empty, before searching a subbstring inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and fixed it. I had an event called "OnLayoutChage" and added `.SetSelection(searchText.Text.Length, searchText.Text.Length);` to fix the issue.

"searchText" is AutoCompleteTextView(it is a kind of EditText type)

```
public void OnLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
     searchText.DropDownAnchor = Resource.Id.appbar;
     searchText.DropDownWidth = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
     .......
     searchText.SetSelection(searchText.Text.Length, searchText.Text.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to get the index of a character on a possible empty string. That's why you get `-1` here

```
String startText = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
int start = startText.indexOf(0);
int end = startText.indexOf(1);
```

You might want to add that statement in a listener e.g. `autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener()` and handle it there where the actual text changes occur.

Comment: how do i use the textchangelistener here